# "Challenge with" or "challenge against"?

Tags: word-choice

Is it proper English to say "my challenge **with** a friend"?

I don't mean to say that I have a challenge *with* him, as in that I don't like him.

I mean to say that I have a challenge *against* him, as in that I have a bet with him (but I'd like to avoid the words "against" and "bet").

Comment: To this American English speaker, it doesn't sound correct to say "I have a challenge" no matter what you put after it!  Yes, "challenge" can be a noun, but we don't use the word that way.  [If you look at this Google Ngrams search, neither "have a challenge with" or "have a challenge against" even rank in the top ten.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+challenge+*&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)  You could say "I have challenged him **to** (something)", though, which sounds more natural.

Comment: @stangdon If you put "I" and "we" in your NGram, you get only three results. "We have a challenge to", "we have a challenge before", and "I have a challenge for".

Answer (score 1):

If you say

> I have a **challenge with** my friend.

it will usually be understood to mean you have some sort of **competition** with your friend.

> I have a **challenge with** my friend to see who can lose 5 pounds fastest.
>   I have a **challenge with** my friend to see who can run fastest.
>   *I have a challenge with my friend to see if they can do something*

You can also say

> I've **challenged** my friend to a duel.
>   I've **put a challenge to** my friend to see if they can swim.

One would not usually say

> **challenge against** *someone*

though one can

> bet **against** *someone* in a challenge

meaning you believe they will fail in the challenge.

Another example

> Teacher: I have a challenge!
>   Students: What is the challenge?
>   Teacher: I challenge you to finish your reading list over the holiday break.
>   Students: Oh no!

Comment: If I search, "[I have a challenge with](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22I+have+a+challenge+with%22)" seems most commonly used in contexts that are synonymous with "I have a problem with", not a competition with. 'I have a challenge with my friend - she's always late and punctuality is very important to me.' "I have challenged my friend." seems far more common if you're talking about a competition.

Comment: Hmm, I would have thought your sentence would be "I'm constantly **challenged** by my friend - she's always late...". "I have challenged my friend" could mean "I have a challenge **for** my friend *to run a mile*" or "I have a challenge **with** my friend *to run a mile against me*".  I have always used it in the same way as "I have a bet with my friend", one of the examples on your link also uses it this way "In the summer I have a **challenge with myself** to see how long I can go without having to wear a bra". (cont)

Comment: The "I have a **challenge with my client**" is an example of the more recent corp-speak, where everything is not a problem but a **challenge** to be overcome. Mind you "challenge" has become a euphemism for "handicap" more recently...

Comment: The NGram shows "have a challenge with" showing up around 1970. None of the contexts I spot checked use it in the sense of a competition. "I have a challenge with" returns no results at all, but I don't think that's definitive. After you get above 4 words, you can't use the interesting tools like _NOUN_ to discern real patterns.

Comment: Hmmm, I see what you mean. In the [**Pepsi Challenge**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepsi_Challenge), wouldn't one say that "Pepsi made/had a challenge with Coke"?

Comment: Pepsi wasn't challenging Coke. Pepsi challenged Coke drinkers to a blind taste test. Pepsi didn't have a "challenge with" anyone.